# Removing everything but the regex result (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++, bookmarks

I have such tags

```
<span class="123">Apple</span>
<span class="123">Red Banana</span>
<span class="123">Yellow Car</span>
<span class="123">Hello everyone</span>
```

that contain different kind of text inside of them (Apple, Red Banana, etc.). The "class" is always the same – "123". 
All these tags are among other tags and HTML elements that I don't need. What I need is to extract only the text inside the `<span class="123"></span>` tag.

I already figured out a regex expression to select these elements:

```
<span class="123">\K.+?(?=</span>)
```

But now I would like to remove everything excepting what I just selected. I already tried to bookmark them and remove the "Unmarked Lines", but I am left with whole lines that I don't actually need.

Does anyone have an idea how I can just replace everything but my selection with "nothing" ?

Best,
john06

Comment: Make use of capture groups to keep/discard what you desire. Search: `(<span class="123">)(.*?)(<\/span>)`. Replace: `$2`

Comment: `(?i-s)<span class="123">(.+?)</span>|.` => `(?{1}$1:)`, then optionally *Edit* > *Line operations* > *Remove Empty Lines*. If you remove `s` from the modifiers, and use `(?{1}$1\n:)`, the second step won't be necessary.